# Is there a difference between $|\arg(z)| < \pi/4$ and $\arg(z) < \pi/4$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a difference between the statements $|\arg(z)| < \pi/4$ and $\arg(z) < \pi/4$; Don't they denote the same condition?

Something confusing, since the modulus is distance from origin, then wouldn't $|\arg(z)|$ refer to numbers $z$ whose angle's "magnitude" is less than $\pi/4$? But this is the same set as those $z$ whose angle is $< \pi /4$.

Answer (score 4):

The inequality may have different solution sets if the branch cut is choosen in different ways.

For example, if we choose the usual branch cut: $\arg(z)\in]-\pi,\pi]$ then the inequality with the absolute value returns only values in the right half plane (in $\color{red}{red}$), whereas the inequality without it returns values even in the III quadrant (in $\color{blue}{blue}$)

[image]

If instead we use the branch cut $[0,2\pi[$ then the two are equivalent and return only the first half quadrant:

[image]

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds 

Comment: My fault! Don't throw your answer answer away... it may contain additional information :)

Comment: Yeah it's gone already . But your's covers mine nicely

Comment: The question uses $\frac \pi 4$, not $\frac \pi 2$, so we don't get whole quadrants.  The spirit of the answer is correct.

Comment: You're right @RossMillikan. Let me fix that